# Flask App: Spotify API OAuth Not Working In Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, flask, spotify

Running into an issue with my flask application. When **not** running the app inside of a docker container, I'm able to successfully authorize via Spotify API.

1. User navigates to `localhost:5000/login`
2. Spotify authorization agreement is displayed
3. User clicks "Agree"
4. User is routed to `localhost:5000/callback` where the text "Success" is displayed

But when I dockerize the flask app, I get the following error when the user clicks "Agree" on the authorize page:

[image: error]

Below is my Dockerfile, and app.py file

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, session, redirect, request, Response, session, make_response
from spotify_connector import SpotifyConnector
connector = SpotifyConnector()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "INDEX"

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    client_id = app.config['CLIENT_ID']
    redirect_uri = app.config['REDIRECT_URI']
    scope = app.config['SCOPE']
    authorize_url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?'
    state_key = connector.create_state_key(15)
    session['state_key'] = state_key
    parameters = 'response_type=code&client_id=' + client_id + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri + '&scope=' + scope + '&state=' + state_key
    response = make_response(redirect(authorize_url + parameters))
    return response


@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    code = request.args.get('code', None)
    state = request.args.get('state', None)
    session.pop('state_key', None)
    payload = connector.getToken(code)
    if payload is not None:
        session['access_token'] = payload['access_token']
        session['refresh_token'] = payload['refresh_token']
        return "SUCCESS"
    else:
        return "FAILURE"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost")
```

Comment: you need to add `logs` and list of `requirements`.

Answer (score 0):

In the part of my code that generates the token for Spotify (where the error was originating), I was retrieving my client id and secret by using:
`CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")`

`CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")`

I threw in a print stament, and saw that Authorization header looked like this --`Authorization: Basic "":""` , when it should look like this `Authorization: Basic CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET`. This confirmed that CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET weren't available.

I added the following to my Dockerfile, and I'm now able to successfully authorize:

`ENV CLIENT_ID=*****`

`ENV CLIENT_SECRET=*****`

Going further, I'm most likely going to get rid of the above two declarations, and add the `os.getenv` declarations to my flask app config file.